# Square brackets in output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec2

When I pass a test, the following outputs: (Using windows)

```
←[32m.←[0m

Finished in 0.63953 seconds
←[32m1 example, 0 failures←[0m

Randomized with seed 46497
```

See all those square brackets? What's with them? Its worse when the tests fail. The output is barely readable due to brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are ANSI color codes that the Windows console does not handle. You can disable then in your Rails log, adding this line in `test.rb` (if you want to remove them only in your test environment) or `application.rb` (for all environments) :

```
config.colorize_logging = false
```

And restart your server.

Comment: removing '--color' from .rspec in application root did it for me. Is there a method for actually seeing colored output in cmd and powershell?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Powershell

Comment: @akashspeaking If this answer worked for you, please don't forget to click the up-arrow and the check mark. It's a small effort for saying thanks.